# connection between airflow and vault

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

I am using Helm Chart airflow version 2.7.0 and hashicrop vault 1.7 in Kubernetes i am trying to establish a connection between the airflow and vault

secrets:
backend: airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend
backend_kwargs:  backend_kwargs: '{"connections_path": "connections", "variables_path": "variables", "mount_point": "airflow", "url": "https://example.com/", "verify": "False"}'

inside helm chart we have added the above

can any one please suggest

thank you in adavance